# DateTime problems when moving to hosted environment

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, datetime, azure

I'm have the following code

```
    Function SaveSession(ByVal model As ViewModelTrainingSession) As JsonResult
...
...
        ses.Date = New DateTime(model.Date.Year, model.Date.Month, model.Date.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local)
        db.TrainingSessions.Add(ses)
        db.SaveChanges()
```

When I run this code local (using debug) with let's say, 2014, 12, 24... The date that is saved in my database is 2014-12-24 00:00:00.000, which is what I want.

Now when I publish my code the server (shared hosting) the same code will end-up putting 2014-12-23 00:00:00.000 in the database.

I was using Azure database before and everything was working well.  Now, I use the database on the new server I'm hosted on.   The code did not change.   But I get that date conversion now which baffles me.  It is only when running from the published code that I get that date difference.  When I run in debug mode local (but connecting to the de remotely) I have no problem

Any ideas?

**Update**

Here's what I do on the client side

```
bSoft.AjaxSaveSession = function (model) {
    /* Convert it to JSON and send it to controller */
    var json = ko.toJSON(model);
    var targetURL = DataSrvOptimaxUrl + '/' + 'SaveSession';
    bSoft.globals.vm.showLoadingWheel(true);
    $.ajax({
        url: targetURL,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Model contain various fields but two of them are named Date and DateStart,  they are populated with javascript Date (I'm using XDate)

The model is sent to the server using the Ajax Call that you see.

On the other side (the server side),  I have a ViewModel (ViewModelTrainingSession) defined with VB.NET.  Again, that model contain a bunch of properties, two of them are Date and DateStart...

There is some magic performed by ASP.NET,  the field are converted from JSON to VB based on the field names.

```
Function SaveSession(ByVal model As ViewModelTrainingSession) As JsonResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        Try
            '....
            'Make sure date is save using time of 00.00.00:000
            ses.StartTime = New DateTime(model.Date.Year, model.Date.Month, model.Date.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local)
            ses.Date = New DateTime(model.Date.Year, model.Date.Month, model.Date.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local)
            '...
            db.TrainingSessions.Add(ses)
            db.SaveChanges()
```

I think the dates get messed up in that conversion from JSON to VB.   It is not the db which is the problem.

I think I'm going to try sending the date component instead of a date,  I'll have a field called year, on called month, on called day, and put the component together on the server... This should prevent conversion and time zone issues.

Comment: different timezones? local code uses local timezone, remote server in a different timezone that happens to be a day ahead?  Regional settings on local system vs server and date/time are likely different.

Comment: Well, did you check the system clock on the new server?

Comment: How is `model` populated?

Comment: @xQbert Has it - this is almost certainly nothing to do with SQL or SQL server and is likely actually working exactly as it should.

Comment: Richard,  I added the signature of the function... The function is called from an Ajax called to a MVC controller.  The model is populated using JavaScript... There is some magic happening on the asp.net side as all the field get mapped to my VB model (the one specified in the signature of the function)... I know the date received if good when I execute un debug... I think the value are fine in the model because the model is sent back to the client (browser) and the date are OK.  It seem to change when saved to the database

Comment: xQbert, probably but what should I do then... I have a date gathered locally, it is send to a remote server... What should I do if I wanted to saved the date properly... I'm a bit stuck to be honest

Comment: I think the best is to use UTC Dates instead of local Dates in both SQL and C#.  Then you don't have timezone and other issues, and you can always convert a UTC date to the correct date for your user in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should switch from DateTimeKind.Local to DateTimeKind.Utc to avoid surprises like this one.

The hour difference stems from your server being in a different time zone than your emulator.

In general you should convert local times to Utc times before storing, and then convert the stored Utc times to local time immediately before displaying them.  And get accustomed to seeing Utc times in your database's raw data. :-)

Comment: Thank you, at first, I did not understand what UTC was for.  Now that you have explained, I think that is the way to go.